# Request returns different data on simulator vs device

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, nsurlrequest, nsurlsession

When I make a request for a webpage on the simulator I get the HTML, but when I make the request from the device (I tried on wifi and cellular networks). This happens consistently.

What would cause this?

EDIT: This is what is returning for me on the device, on the simulator I get the real page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

<html>

<head>

<title>Error</title>

<meta name=vs_defaultClientScript content="JavaScript">

<meta name=vs_targetSchema content="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5">

<meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 7.1">

<meta name=ProgId content=VisualStudio.HTML>

<meta name=Originator content="Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 7.1">

<link rel="stylesheet" id="style" runat="server" type="text/css" href="Data/style/mojo1.css" />

</head>

<body >

<br /><br />

<table ID="Table1">

<tr>

    <td width="100"></td>

    <td align="center">



    </td>
</tr>

<tr>

    <td width="100"></td>

    <td width="500">

        <p style="font-family:arial sans-serif;font-size:large">

        Sorry!

        </p>

        <p style="font-family:arial sans-serif;font-size:large">

        A server error has occurred.<br />

        The error has been logged and will be reviewed as soon as possible.

        It may have been a momentary problem; use the back button to try again or go back to the

        <a href="http://metrotransit.org/home.aspx">home</a> page.

        For assistance, call 612-373-3333 to speak with a transit representative.

        </p>

    </td>

</tr>

</table>

</body>

</html>
```

EDIT: I know it's not the User Agent. I made a custom configuration and the issue continues.

EDIT: Issue continues with NSURLRequest as well as NSURLSession.

Comment: Can you please paste the Url?

Comment: [Great question!](http://metrotransit.org)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My phone was in my native language which is not english. Changing hardware phone's language to english solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**It is working for me!!!**

My code is as follow:

```
-(IBAction)web_pressed:(id)sender
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://metrotransit.org/"]];
}
```

**Let me know if you have any problem.**

Comment: Is this this helpful to you?

Comment: No, still not working for me. This isn't a web view, I'm trying to download the HTML.